# how to upgrade the ruby version from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 on site5.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi I am wanting to install my website on a site5.com website but I am having difficulty. The ruby version on the actual site is 1.8.7 but the ruby version I use on my local computer is 1.9.3. How do I upgrade to ruby 1.9.3 without the use of sudo, apt-get install, and apt-get update?

If anyone knows some ways to get in without having to use sudo or the above, I would be very greatful for an answer to this problem.

Comment: Why aren't you using `rvm` on your local computer, to match the website's Ruby version? (And is `rvm` the answer to your question?)

Comment: Because RVM doesn't exist on that site and all the methods to get rvm fail. I am not using the site anymore. My local machine supports rvm the server doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I don't think you can at the moment. But as of a few weeks ago, it [looks like](http://www.site5.com/blog/programming/ruby-rails/) they're starting to convert to 1.9.3 (emphasis added):

> We will begin the process of updating all servers to a newer version of Phusion Passenger (the 4.0 branch) in November. That deployment will allow you to use any version of Ruby — including 1.9 and 2.0 — inside your Rack-based applications (e.g. Rails).
>
> **We will then begin work on changing the default Ruby across our entire fleet from Ruby 1.8.7 to 1.9.3.** You will receive ample notification for this change, but if your application only functions on Ruby 1.8.7, you will be able to change the Ruby version per-application and per-account (via .htaccess) using the PassengerRuby option available in Phusion Passenger 4. You can then compile your own version of Ruby 1.8 inside of your account for your legacy applications.